# How to use a custom function in max(x, key=custom_function) function?

Tags: python, max, built-in

I have a custom data type, say: `mytime`, which represent hours and minutes, such as 29:45, it is 29 hours and 45 minutes.

I want to use `max` built-in function to find the item in a list of lists, whose sum of its elements is the greatest, where all lists contain values of `mytime` type.

```
x = [[a, b], [c, d]]
```

a,b,c,d are of `mytime` type.

```
max(x, key=sum)
```

won't work here, because a,b,c,d, are not integers.

If I type `a + b` at python command line, I get the sum of these two time values, result is of `mytime` type, without any errors.

How do I use `max` function here?

Comment: So given `x = [[a, b], [c, d]]`, you want the sublist of `x` such that the sum of the `mytime` elements in that sublist is the greatest (in terms of hours and minutes)? Or do you want to know just the greatest sum of time from one of those sublists?

Comment: I want to have the sublist of x, whose sum of elements are greatest. For example if `x = [[02:00, 03:00], [09:00, 04:00]]` then I want to get `[09:00,04:00]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's say your class looks like this:

```
class mytime(object):

    def __init__(self, h, m):
        self.h = h
        self.m = m

    def __add__(self, other):
        return mytime(self.h + other.h, self.m + other.m)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '%i:%i' % (self.h, self.m)
```

and you use it like this:

```
a = mytime(10, 10)        
b = mytime(2, 22)
print a + b
```

and it will work as expect:

> 12:32

---

**Problem:**

What you want to do is:

```
l = [a, b]
print sum(l)
```

but it will fail:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'mytime'

The problem is that the `sum` function will start with `0` and will add up all values of the list. It will try to evaluate

```
0 + mytime(10, 10)
```

which will fail.

---

**Solution:**

The solution to your problem is implementing the `__radd__` function, which represents "reverse add" and is called when the arguments can't be resolved in the "forward" direction. For example, `x + y` is evaluated as `x.__add__(y)` if possible, but if that doesn't exist then Python tries `y.__radd__(x)`.

So you can add the following method to your class:

```
def __radd__(self, other):
    return mytime(self.h, self.m)
```

and the `sum` function will work for you (in this implementation ignoring the `other` value, which is probably fine in your case).

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure using `a + b` works? All `sum` does is repeatedly apply `+` to adjacent elements (it's the same as `reduce(operator.add, sequence)` with a special case to break on strings)... So if it does work - then `max(x, key=sum)` should just work -- **as long as `mydate` supports comparison operators - eg `__gt__`, `__eq__`, `__lt__`**

**Example**

You need to have `__gt__` defined for max to work...

```
class mydate(object):
    def __init__(self, num):
        self.num = num
    def __add__(self, other): # make sure sum works
        return self.num + other.num
    def __gt__(self, other): # make sure max can do > comparison
        return self.num > other.num
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'date: {}'.format(self.num)


x = mydate(3)
y = mydate(5)
z = mydate(2)

print max([x,y,z], key=sum)
```

Comment: Yes `a+b` works. But `max(x, key=sum)` didn't work because I get: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'mytime'` error.

Comment: @alwbtc have expanded answer - you might need to modify `__add__` or add `__iadd__` to work around `+'ing with `int`s

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own sum function:

```
def my_sum(item):
    return sum(60 * e[0] + e[1] for e in item)

x = [[(2,0), (3,0)], [(9, 0), (4, 0)]]
print max(x, key=my_sum)
```

I have represented your `mytime` data structure as tuples (with hours and minutes) so you may need to adjust `my_sum` to your data structure. The only requirement is that the hours and minutes of a `mytime` can be filled in for `e[0]` and `e[1]` respectively.

The above code returns the greatest element (in this case `[(9, 0), (4, 0)]`).